# Windows 10 - Office 365 - OUTLOOK

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, office365

I use Office 365 and have many sub-folders in OUTLOOK to sort emails.

I receive the following message:

> Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following: folder exists

This message is frustrating since it does not name the duplicated folder.

Is there an easy way to find the duplicate and resolve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following: Email is too large, limit size to less than 20 MB](https://superuser.com/questions/806758/your-imap-server-wants-to-alert-you-to-the-following-email-is-too-large-limit)